# SVG Error in safari (using iframe to load)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, safari

I have a external svg file , the problem is with safari it is giving me a error of
**Premature end of document**

I tried to load svg with iframe , object with type="image/svg+xml" but same result

This is the error
[image]

This is svg file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrvawxu1au656jm/1592808712247_d3-celestial.svg?dl=0

Comment: If it only does it with that particular SVG, then I would say the problem is probably in that particular SVG file's markup itself. Which we can't really help with much since you didn't provide it.

Comment: Ok wait providing svg also

Comment: And what happens at line 1, column 524288? Also, such a long string often has problems being transferred, if you look at popular libraries, they'll split line to ~ 30000 chars length.

Comment: The svg is too big , does size of svg matters? because on chrome its working fine but only in safari this error is there

Comment: The file there is ending with `<path class="star" d="M277.2035270445957,841`. The only valid ending for an svg file is `</svg>`. Some of your data is being dropped. Chrome also does complain about it. (I guess something that doesn't know svg did intentionnaly crop it to be 512KB).

Comment: Thanks , i checked it actually i am generating this svg from a library then i post it through a form , don't know why in safari it is not completely posted